# Yii2 Advanced Module 'mysqli' already loaded

Tags: mysqli, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Today I tried to login in my web that build with Yii2 Advanced is host on web hosting not on local but I get a message that I don't know the cause, my web was working before; But now if I try to login or signup I get the error message

> ```
> PHP Core Warning – yii\base\ErrorException
>
> Module 'mysqli' already loaded
> 2. yii\base\ErrorHandler::handleFatalError()
> $_COOKIE = [
>     '_csrf-frontend' => '1eeb7f614f48a8cd57c96d2d21c90a7a465fbc93f9b618433a36ef30c3ddc109a:2:{i:0;s:14:"_csrf-frontend";i:1;s:32:"oe-XYnP-spWkfAnAr60krL0ZcbasV903";}',
>     'advanced-frontend' => '204297706ba2ce08d26572dc47df00ea',
>     '_identity-frontend' => '428bd26204dadccf0bf60576cce5d967f7e28a7f7737adbfea493f47b38ab2fca:2:{i:0;s:18:"_identity-frontend";i:1;s:49:"[1049,"E0Wg4yb1hO6PcuEQovAQRFVoPylkj_59",2592000]";}',
> ];
>
> $_SESSION = [
>     '__flash' => [],
>     '__id' => 1049,
> ];
> ```

I did check my php.ini file but I think everything is alright on my php.ini

```
allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = On
display_errors = Off
enable_dl = Off
file_uploads = On
max_execution_time = 120
max_input_time = 240
max_input_vars = 1000
memory_limit = 256M
post_max_size = 50M
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.save_path = "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php72"
upload_max_filesize = 50M
zlib.output_compression = Off
```

I didn't change anything on my yii2 files everything's work fine before the problem start today

My shell access php --ini

```
[groopakc@server5 ~]$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/01-ioncube.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/bcmath.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/bz2.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/ctype.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/curl.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/dba.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/dom.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/enchant.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/exif.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/fileinfo.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/ftp.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/gd.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/gettext.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/iconv.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/imap.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/intl.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/json.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/ldap.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/mbstring.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/mcrypt.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/mysqlnd.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/mysqlnd_mysql.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/mysqlnd_mysqli.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/odbc.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/pdo.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/pdo_mysqlnd.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/pdo_odbc.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/pdo_pgsql.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/pdo_sqlite.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/pgsql.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/phar.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/posix.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/pspell.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/shmop.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/simplexml.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/snmp.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/soap.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/sockets.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/sourceguardian.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/sqlite3.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/sysvmsg.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/sysvsem.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/sysvshm.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/tokenizer.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/xml.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/xml_wddx.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/xmlreader.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/xmlrpc.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/xmlwriter.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/xsl.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/zendguard.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/zip.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.d/zzzzzzz-pecl.ini

[groopakc@server5 ~]$
```

My htaccess is

```
#IndexIgnore *
Options -Indexes


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>

# Deny accessing below extensions
<Files ~ "(.json|.lock|.git)">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>

# Deny accessing dot files
RewriteRule (^\.|/\.) - [F]

# BEGIN cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
# Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
# To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
# For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)
<IfModule php7_module>
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_execution_time 120
   php_value max_input_time 240
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 256M
   php_value post_max_size 50M
   php_value upload_max_filesize 50M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php72"
</IfModule>
<IfModule lsapi_module>
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_execution_time 120
   php_value max_input_time 240
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 256M
   php_value post_max_size 50M
   php_value upload_max_filesize 50M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php72"
</IfModule>
# END cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php72” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

The requirements.php file is

```
<?php
/**
 * Application requirement checker script.
 *
 * In order to run this script use the following console command:
 * php requirements.php
 *
 * In order to run this script from the web, you should copy it to the web root.
 * If you are using Linux you can create a hard link instead, using the following command:
 * ln ../requirements.php requirements.php
 */

// you may need to adjust this path to the correct Yii framework path
$frameworkPath = dirname(__FILE__) . '/vendor/yiisoft/yii2';

if (!is_dir($frameworkPath)) {
    echo '<h1>Error</h1>';
    echo '<p><strong>The path to yii framework seems to be incorrect.</strong></p>';
    echo '<p>You need to install Yii framework via composer or adjust the framework path in file <abbr title="' . __FILE__ . '">' . basename(__FILE__) . '</abbr>.</p>';
    echo '<p>Please refer to the <abbr title="' . dirname(__FILE__) . '/README.md">README</abbr> on how to install Yii.</p>';
}

require_once $frameworkPath . '/requirements/YiiRequirementChecker.php';
$requirementsChecker = new YiiRequirementChecker();

$gdMemo = $imagickMemo = 'Either GD PHP extension with FreeType support or ImageMagick PHP extension with PNG support is required for image CAPTCHA.';
$gdOK = $imagickOK = false;

if (extension_loaded('imagick')) {
    $imagick = new Imagick();
    $imagickFormats = $imagick->queryFormats('PNG');
    if (in_array('PNG', $imagickFormats)) {
        $imagickOK = true;
    } else {
        $imagickMemo = 'Imagick extension should be installed with PNG support in order to be used for image CAPTCHA.';
    }
}

if (extension_loaded('gd')) {
    $gdInfo = gd_info();
    if (!empty($gdInfo['FreeType Support'])) {
        $gdOK = true;
    } else {
        $gdMemo = 'GD extension should be installed with FreeType support in order to be used for image CAPTCHA.';
    }
}

/**
 * Adjust requirements according to your application specifics.
 */
$requirements = array(
    // Database :
    array(
        'name' => 'PDO extension',
        'mandatory' => true,
        'condition' => extension_loaded('pdo'),
        'by' => 'All DB-related classes',
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'PDO SQLite extension',
        'mandatory' => false,
        'condition' => extension_loaded('pdo_sqlite'),
        'by' => 'All DB-related classes',
        'memo' => 'Required for SQLite database.',
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'PDO MySQL extension',
        'mandatory' => false,
        'condition' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql'),
        'by' => 'All DB-related classes',
        'memo' => 'Required for MySQL database.',
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'PDO PostgreSQL extension',
        'mandatory' => false,
        'condition' => extension_loaded('pdo_pgsql'),
        'by' => 'All DB-related classes',
        'memo' => 'Required for PostgreSQL database.',
    ),
    // Cache :
    array(
        'name' => 'Memcache extension',
        'mandatory' => false,
        'condition' => extension_loaded('memcache') || extension_loaded('memcached'),
        'by' => '<a href="http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-caching-memcache.html">MemCache</a>',
        'memo' => extension_loaded('memcached') ? 'To use memcached set <a href="http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-caching-memcache.html#$useMemcached-detail">MemCache::useMemcached</a> to <code>true</code>.' : ''
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'APC extension',
        'mandatory' => false,
        'condition' => extension_loaded('apc'),
        'by' => '<a href="http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-caching-apccache.html">ApcCache</a>',
    ),
    // CAPTCHA:
    array(
        'name' => 'GD PHP extension with FreeType support',
        'mandatory' => false,
        'condition' => $gdOK,
        'by' => '<a href="http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-captcha-captcha.html">Captcha</a>',
        'memo' => $gdMemo,
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'ImageMagick PHP extension with PNG support',
        'mandatory' => false,
        'condition' => $imagickOK,
        'by' => '<a href="http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-captcha-captcha.html">Captcha</a>',
        'memo' => $imagickMemo,
    ),
    // PHP ini :
    'phpExposePhp' => array(
        'name' => 'Expose PHP',
        'mandatory' => false,
        'condition' => $requirementsChecker->checkPhpIniOff("expose_php"),
        'by' => 'Security reasons',
        'memo' => '"expose_php" should be disabled at php.ini',
    ),
    'phpAllowUrlInclude' => array(
        'name' => 'PHP allow url include',
        'mandatory' => false,
        'condition' => $requirementsChecker->checkPhpIniOff("allow_url_include"),
        'by' => 'Security reasons',
        'memo' => '"allow_url_include" should be disabled at php.ini',
    ),
    'phpSmtp' => array(
        'name' => 'PHP mail SMTP',
        'mandatory' => false,
        'condition' => strlen(ini_get('SMTP')) > 0,
        'by' => 'Email sending',
        'memo' => 'PHP mail SMTP server required',
    ),
);
$requirementsChecker->checkYii()->check($requirements)->render();
```

This is my PHP Version Configuration
[image]

Comment: run the `php --ini` on the terminal and add the output, it is most probably what the error says you are loading the module twice somewhere, or add the section from you `php.ini` where you have listed all the extensions.or alternatively addd the whole file using the http://pastebin.com

Comment: the web is hosted on web hosting, which module is loaded twice

Comment: `php_mysqli.dll` is the one that is loaded twice look into the extensions section

Comment: Ok I will look if I can find it and give a reply

Comment: I didn't find anything about extensions in cpanel

Comment: you need to connect via `ssh` to your site and run the command `php --ini` and it will list the modules loaded, look for `mysqli` if listed twice.

Comment: I add shell access php --ini to my question, and an Image of php version configuration .If you can help me; mysqli is listed only once

Comment: doesnt look like that the extension is enabled twice from the image you have provided

Comment: yes and that why I don't understand why I'm getting this error and how to fix it

Comment: @Bynd Did you solve the issue?

Comment: no I didn't find any solution. I did changed the web hosting to another company; it's working good now but I'm afraid if the problem back again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, downgrading to PHP7 fixed my issue.